# How to count leading zeros in a string as the length?

Tags: java, numbers, calc

I have to make this calculator sort of program, that count number of elements in string as numbers,(have to use string because must handle integer overflow).
I am having the issue that it does not count the first zeros, for example:
1233 count would be 4
0001233 count would still be 4, but i need it to add the first 000 so it comes 7.
Any idea how to implement this without much change?

```
package com.company;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your number here: ");

        BigInteger input = scan.nextBigInteger();
        String inputstr = input.toString();
        System.out.println("Number of elements: " + inputstr.length());
        System.out.println("Number of different numbers: " + inputstr.chars().distinct().count());
        int number = input.intValue();
        int even_count=0;
        int odd_count=0;

        while (number>0){
            int rem=number%10;

            if (rem%2==0){
                even_count++;
            }
            else{
                odd_count++;
            }
            number=number/10;
        }
        System.out.println("Even numbers: "+ even_count);
        System.out.println("Odd numbers: "+ odd_count);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe it would work if i could put the front zeros at the end somehow... that would count them

Answer (score 0):

You can try first to read input as String and then create a new BigInteger from it, like this:

```java
String inputstr = scan.next();
System.out.println("Number of elements: " + inputstr.length());
System.out.println("Number of different numbers: " + inputstr.chars().distinct().count());
BigInteger input = new BigInteger(inputstr);
```